# Replace YAML placeholders From Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a cucumber testing repository written in ruby. The repo has yaml files for different environments but the yaml files contain some similar code:

Example

`dev.yml`

```
home_url: http://abc-dev
```

`test.yml`

```
home_url: http://abc-test
```

In this example, both yaml files have the same key name and the value is literally the same minus the environment at the end. In situations like this I want to move similar key-value pairs to a common.yml file and use a variable. Something like this:

`common.yml`

```
home_url: http://abc-{{env_var}}
```

Now ideally, the `env_var` variable would not be declared (unless necessary) and in ruby when I start the command line to run tests I can declare the environment there and then pick up the environment from the command line:

`cucumber TEST_ENV=dev`

How can I do this in ruby? I'm on ruby 2.5.5 currently.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too pretty, but you can achieve that using ERB in your YAML.

Suppose you have `common.yml` like this:

```
home_url: http://abc-<%= ENV['TEST_ENV'] %>
```

Then you can write a Ruby script to evaluate ERB inside:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'
yaml = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read('common.yml')).result)
p yaml
```

... and run it:

```
> TEST_ENV=test ruby load_yaml.rb
{"home_url"=>"http://abc-test"}
> TEST_ENV=dev ruby load_yaml.rb
{"home_url"=>"http://abc-dev"}
```